# Regex to detect empty tags recursively

Tags: regex

I need to detect all `<p>` tags that do not contain text, whatever the `<p>` tag contains other empty tags (such as `<strong>`, `<em>`, `<span>`...).
Then I need to replace the content of the `<p>` tag by a `&nbsp;` entity.

A few examples below :

1 - I want to transform the HTML below :
`<p style="font-size: 16px;"></p>`
in :
`<p style="font-size: 16px;">&nbsp;</p>`

2 - I want to transform the HTML below :
`<p style="font-size: 16px;"><em></em></p>`
in :
`<p style="font-size: 16px;">&nbsp;</p>`

3 - I want to transform the HTML below :
`<p style="font-size: 16px;"><strong><em></em></strong></p>`
in :
`<p style="font-size: 16px;">&nbsp;</p>`

4 - I DON'T want to transform the HTML below :
`<p style="font-size: 16px;"><em>lorem ipsum</em></p>`

I've been able to build a regex which works only for a single tag (or none) contained in the `<p>` tag :

`<p([^>]*)>(?:<[^\/>][^>]*><\/[^>]+>)?<\/p>`

I don't find a way to make it work with several tags imbricated in the `<p>` tag (example 3).

Any idea ?

Comment: [Regular expressions aren't the right solution to this problem](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/). What's the *real* issue you're trying to solve here? Why do you need to inject non-breaking spaces into textless elements?

Comment: Easy - [`(<p[^<]*?>)(?:\s+|<[^<]*?>)*(<\/p>)`](https://regex101.com/r/mH0wT4/1) -- > `$1&nbsp;$2`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wrong, as your regex will make this `some text <p><strong></strong></p><p></p><p><em></em></p> some text` into `some text <p>&nbsp;</p> some text`.

Comment: @SlavikMeltser: That is exactly what I wanted to achieve with my regex. So, for me it is absolutely *right*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but the expected answer should be `some text <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p> some text`

Comment: That is not a problem - [`(<p[^<]*?>)(?:\s+|<(?!p[\s>])[^<]*?>)*(<\/p>)`](https://regex101.com/r/mH0wT4/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks that's exactly the solution !

Comment: @AndréDion I know regex is not the ideal solution for parsing HTML but in my case that's what I want to do

Comment: Actually, in JS you could also use a DOM parser.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew OK, but I think the regex solution is lighter for my case (1 line of code)

Answer (score 1):

Use a beautiful DOM parser instead:

```
<?php

$data = <<<DATA
<div>
    <p style="font-size: 16px;"></p>
    <p style="font-size: 16px;"><em></em></p>
    <p style="font-size: 16px;">&nbsp;</p>
    <p style="font-size: 16px;"><strong><em></em></strong></p>
    <p style="font-size: 16px;">&nbsp;</p>
    <p style="font-size: 16px;"><em>lorem ipsum</em></p>
</div>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
#$dom->removeChild($dom->doctype);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$lines = $xpath->query("//p[not(normalize-space())]");
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    while ($line->hasChildNodes()) {
        $line->removeChild($line->firstChild);
    }
    $line->nodeValue = '&nbsp;';
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
?>
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/R54uBb).

---

This produces:

```
<div>
    <p style="font-size: 16px;">&nbsp;</p>
    <p style="font-size: 16px;">&nbsp;</p>
    <p style="font-size: 16px;">&nbsp;</p>
    <p style="font-size: 16px;">&nbsp;</p>
    <p style="font-size: 16px;">&nbsp;</p>
    <p style="font-size: 16px;"><em>lorem ipsum</em></p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but I forgot to say that I need to do that in Javascript

Comment: Use AJAX with the code above then. JS has far less possibilities to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily accomplish it using JavaScript within a DOM structure, which by the way is much faster than using Regular Expressions, because regex parsing the whole string, when browsing in a DOM tree you are looking for an already parsed information (Element's data like `textContent` is a static data, and it is not calculated when you call it).

```
var elements = documnet.getElementsByTagName('p'), element, i;
for ( i in elements )
{
    element = elements[i];
    if ( element instanceof HTMLParagraphElement
         && !element.textContent.trim() )
    {
        element.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
    }
}
```

Good luck.